# I have a problem installing docker, how to fix it?

Tags: docker

When I run the installer and it hit's me with configuration, I check them both and then I hit "ok" button. After that I get a "Installation Failed" and this message:

```
Component CommunityInstaller.AutoStartAction failed: Access to the registry key 'HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run' is denied.
   at CommunityInstaller.InstallWorkflow.<DoHandleD4WPackageAsync>d__30.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at CommunityInstaller.InstallWorkflow.<DoProcessAsync>d__23.MoveNext()
```

I really don't know what to do. I'm using windows 10 on a ThinkPad x240

I try run it as administrator but it didn't work. I looked online and didn't find a solution.